# Same container width & height as loading image

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic Framework / Angularjs and it is fantastic.

I'm writing and application. It requires to load images in ng-repeat list. everything is fine except image showing loading and height of container changes. I don't want that. 
I want to: 
1 - keep the same height and width as loading image.
2 - show image after fully loaded (so do not show half).

more like as in Facebook App.

How can i do it in ionic/angular/css?

will be thankful if can share codes...

thanks
-Navi

Comment: seems more of a css `min-height/min-width` issue.

Comment: I would check the container which holds your image, to make sure that the height/width attributes remain constant regarding of the image contents. It would be possible to help you better if you shared any code you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

In reference to your issue:
Always use min-height and min-width according what your image would be.
As you have explained you need a similar behavior like facebook, if you properly check the facebook page it always has a fixed height and width whenever a image is going to load.
please view below code:

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="path of image to be loaded" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container{
    min-height:500px;
    min-width:500px;
}
.image-container img{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Using AngularJS will have an additional advantage of showing the image post loading use ng-src.
Also avoid using a Very High Definition images for a web page as it slow downs your entire page loading.

Please go through preloading of images in case of higher resolution images, see link below.
https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If your picture size is determined, you can use `min-height` and `min-width` to fixed width.
You can write a directive to load images by JavaScript, setting `<img>` `src` in `onload` event.